# GreenDAO with proguard: NoSuchFieldException: TABLENAME

Tags: android, greendao

This issue has been occurring for a couple of months when I started using greenDAO for Android.
In my app I have proguard and already made the changes suggested in greenDAO FAQ

`-keepclassmembers class * extends de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao {
    public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
-keep class **$Properties`

Also, I've tried some alternatives posted here in this [Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/greendao/tyqjrx2otVo)

But I still get crashes like this

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: TABLENAME
   at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1104)
   at de.greenrobot.dao.internal.DaoConfig.(DaoConfig.java:56)
   at de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDaoMaster.registerDaoClass(AbstractDaoMaster.java:44)
```

The interesting point is that this crash only occurs in Samsung devices. most often in Lollipop.

Is anyone having the same issue as me?

Comment: If you are using GreenDAO 3, then you must replace `de.greenrobot` with `org.greenrobot`.

Answer (score 3):

1.

```
-libraryjars libs/greendao-1.3.7.jar
-keep class de.greenrobot.dao.** {*;}
 #保持greenDao的方法不被混淆
-keepclassmembers class * extends de.greenrobot.dao.AbstractDao {
  #用来保持生成的表名不被混淆     
 public static java.lang.String TABLENAME; } 
 -keep class **$Properties
```

2.   maybe u havant add some common keep rule

Comment: Actually I also tried these variations, as they were suggested at the Google group discussion I mentioned...